# Prevent WSDL generation from including certain fields

Tags: java, web-services, eclipse, wsdl, apache-axis

I'm using Axis2 and Eclipse to create my webservice.  I have created my schema object to be included in the WSDL, but I don't want some fields to be included in this process.

Reason is that these same objects will be persisted in database using hibernate.  I added transient into the field class declaration but I'm still seeing the field in the WSDL!!!

Is there a way to prevent certain fields from being included in the WSDL?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `excludeProperties` in `services.xml`

```
<parameter name="beanPropertyRules">
    <bean class="sample.Address" excludeProperties="street,number" />
    <bean class="sample.AddressParent" excludeProperties="zipcode" />
</parameter>
```

See http://wso2.org/library/2893

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a comma to separate the excludeProperties use a pipe ("|")

Comment: For everyone interested in the reason: Axis2 uses regular expressions to match class and property against the configured string, it doesn't just split on "," or such. Therefore multiple properties separated by "," won't ever work anymore. Check the implementation: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.axis2/axis2-kernel/1.6.2/org/apache/axis2/deployment/util/BeanExcludeInfo.java#BeanExcludeInfo.isExcludedProperty%28java.lang.String%29