# Avoiding certain attributes in an Object from being included in WSDL

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

I have a web service class that takes an object as an argument. The object has many fields but not all the field are required by the web service. I am creating the web service using eclipse web service wizard & Axis2. Is there a way to stop those attributes from appearing in the wsdl generated by the eclipse wizard. I tried setting up the beanPorpertyRules in the services.xml as shown below, but that didn't work either. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<service name="VerifyService" >
<Description>
    Please Type your service description here
</Description>
<messageReceivers>
    <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
    <messageReceiver  mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"  class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
</messageReceivers>
<parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">xxxxxxxxx</parameter>
<parameter name="beanPropertyRules">
    <bean class="xxxxxxxxx" excludeProperties="orderID,ship,bill,items,itemIds,mercTotal,ordTotal,cCode" />
</parameter>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent WSDL generation from including certain fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924884/prevent-wsdl-generation-from-including-certain-fields)

Comment: I have been through that post and got the idea of beanPropertyRules from that post. However my question is that even after adding that I am not able to exclude the properties.

Comment: My web service class takes the object as an argument instead of instantiating it in the example shown in the other post. Does that have to do anything with the issue I am experiencing.

Comment: It looks like you can exclude properties from the result object, not from parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out you have to use a pipe instead of the comma to separate the exclude properties.